# CSS precedence, when styling with JS

Tags: javascript, css

This question is in regards to precedence. I have an `<ul>` that contains my nav items in `<li>` I have an id for the `<ul>` which I use to reference the `<li>` and `<a>` tags nested within for styling. This all works fine, but when I use JavaScript to add a class to these specific `<a>` tags, to change the appearance when hovering over the links nothing happens.

I know the code is correct as I have tested it, but it just seems the ID styles take precedence over the Class's in when referencing styles.

How would I go about finding a solution, one idea I have is to remove the existing ID on mouseenter before adding the class, and then visa versa on mouseleave. Is there an easier solution?

Comment: We will need to see your selectors for both the CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding !important to the end of your css for values which require overriding.

```
.class { color: #fbfbfb !important; }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Never used !important before, simple solution, really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

ID styles are stronger, but you can use it when adding class for styling links as well.

So, if your menu is

```
<ul id="main">
    <li><a href=#></a></li>
</ul>
```

And JS adds class "hovered" to  element, then use CSS

```
#main .hovered {
.. styles here
}
```

Comment: Here's some additional reading on CSS Specificity:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/